# Does this Google Android Note4 activity look legit?

Tags: android, google, account-security

I noticed some activity on my phone via myactivity.google.com that has been occurring recently at 3 AM which I am very suspicious of.  While I am frequently up at that hour I know it's happening when I'm not up.  Details:

- Started a week or two ago
- Always occurs at exactly 3 AM
- It may coincide with new/updated apps and or permission changes but I'm not sure
- No visible changes to the phone during that time, eg. screen doesn't turn on, indicator lights look normal

Am I being paranoid?

The 2nd part of this question is, presuming this activity is does not appear normal what would be the best approach to acquire more information about what is going on? I'm right at home on with a traditional web/app server, but not sure where to look in Android.  Device is an un-rooted Verizon Note 4

[image: Activity detail 1]

[image: Activity detail 2]

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to point to a culprit, although I highly doubt someone compromising phones would run a task on a timeline, it is possible, but this would be a brazen and obvious attack if so.  Can you go in to your device's Settings, tap Google and then >  More (Which looks like the three dots on top of each other in the top right) and then Usage & diagnostics.  Is this turned on or off?

Comment: @cclater the myactivity timeline is literally everything you do on your phone (and a bunch of stuff you don't) as a way for google to be "Transparent" about how much they mine your life.  Literally when your alarm goes off, when you press the home key, make a call, ask for directions, read an email, turn the ringer volume off, it's all there. So it wouldn't be surprising if malware activity did show up there (it would be hard to do anything meaningful on the device without it happening) but in this case, its really doubtful.

Comment: @cclater Settings>Google>More>Usage & Diagnostics is off (turned off 2 days ago when I noticed this, I did just double check though), but yet both activity entries showed up last night @ 3 AM again.  Perhaps this is Google logging Samsung's data collecting activities.

Comment: @Stoney interesting, yeah Samsung, as well as most other phone manufacturers and provider so like to load their own bloatware logging software. I would be surprised if you were correct and Samsung was also running some diagnostic in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can vouch that the activity is "normal" at least as "normal" as Google's hive mind panopticon can be.  I have a device running 6.0 and a device running 7.0 (they are unrooted Samsung with minimal apps and no sideloads or Knox triggers which pretty well assures that there's not anything malicious running) and they both also show the 3:00 a.m. activity similar to yours, not every day and not each type but both do show it a few times over the past week.